# application not update my previoues application after download

Tags: android

I have download new version of android application but in my mobile previoues version is running but when i download .it download but not update myprevioes version . can you tell me issue

Comment: You downloading app from playstore?

Comment: no, i have download from web server for testing  application.after notification message click on ok tp update my application .app download but not update my previoues application to override.its download and disappear

Comment: Once uninstall and then install again.

Comment: same issue sir ,after 100%  download it disappear

Comment: sit can we open direct google play url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pkg

Comment: Change pkg with your package name.

Comment: i try sir but when i click open  (google play ) back on my application page not download